# Split Access database in separate files

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to export each table of one database in separate accdb files and I don't get it.

With the following code -> https://www.devhut.net/2012/09/27/ms-access-vba-export-database-objects-to-another-database/ the destination database must already exist.

How can I create e.g. for table1 the file table1.accdb and export only one table into this database? If the main database has 10 tables 10 files should be created and the belonging table should export as well.

Comment: You can use the [CreateDatabase method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-createdatabase-method-dao) to make a new, empty database file as the destination for an exported table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```vb
Public Function ExportTables()

    Const Path      As String = "C:\Test\"

    Dim Workspace   As DAO.Workspace
    Dim Database    As DAO.Database
    Dim Table       As DAO.TableDef
    Dim Tablename   As String

    Set Workspace = DBEngine(0)

    For Each Table In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Table.Attributes = 0 Then
            ' This is a local table and not a system table.
            Tablename = Table.Name
            Set Database = Workspace.CreateDatabase(Path & Tablename, dbLangGeneral)
            DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", Database.Name, acTable, Tablename, Tablename
            Debug.Print "Exported " & Tablename
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: wow that's it. Thank you so much. I didn't found the CreateDatabase function which seems pretty easy (but not for me)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to create a Database

```
Private Sub CreateDatabase(nameOfDatabase As String)
On Error Resume Next
 Dim accessApp As Access.Application
   Set accessApp = New Access.Application
   accessApp.DBEngine.CreateDatabase nameOfDatabase & ".accdb", DB_LANG_GENERAL
   accessApp.Quit
   Set accessApp = Nothing

End Sub
```